# Studies on performance comparison of portfolio theories?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization

Are there any papers doing as broad as possible comparison of various portfolio theories performance?

For example, compare specific theories:

1. MPT
2. Risk parity
3. Black-Litterman
4. etc

or compare models:

1. Mean variance optimization
2. Risk allocation
3. Bayesian probabilities
4. etc

I understand it is impossible to compare **ALL** theories and models, but it would be interesting to see somebody comparing at least more than two theories (which seems to be the usual case for academia).

Comment: related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/reference-request-horse-race-for-portfolio-allocation